# Javascript function written in script tag call from Js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am in trouble. I have cshtml file where in script tag i have function call **setFormsvalue**

```
<script>
 function setFormValues(selectedItem) {

            $('#MURWorksheetId').val(selectedItem.MURWorksheetId);
            $('#PatientId').val(selectedItem.PatientId);
            $('#txtMURDate').val(selectedItem.MURDate2);
            $('#txtPatientName').val(selectedItem["objPatientModel.Title"]);     
        }

</script>
```

I am calling this method from js file which i have imported in cshtml file.

```
var selectedItem = entityGrid.dataItem(row);
                setFormValues(selectedItem);
```

its giving error setFormValues not defined.

Comment: Where you are importing the js file, and where in the page you have the `script` tag? is it in the head or the body?

Comment: please share the order of import and script tag and also explain is `setFormValues(selectedItem);` called on import load or you explicitly call it

Comment: Page
`<Script> function setFormValues(){} </script>`

Js file
`<script src="@Url.Content("~/PageScripts/Transactions/MUR/SuggestedQuestions.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

both the functions are written in document.ready();

Comment: script tag is independent not on page load its in body.

Comment: solved it was because of method scope .